# quiero enviar alertas por correo electronico

Tags: php

quiero enviar alertas por correo electronico cuando la cita del usuario esta a 3 dias de cumplir su fecha de vencimiento. pero me genera este error.

> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /usr/home/anasdprueba.com/web/envioemail.php

supuestamente la consulta esta mal, gracias de antemano

```
$sql = "select agenda.*, usuario.email from agenda inner join usuario ON agenda.idusuario = usuario.idusuario".
    "where fecha_fin = date_sub(curdate(), interval 3 day)";      

    $rpt = mysqli_query($cn,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());
    $asunto = 'Hola Usuario'; 
    $cuerpo = ' 
    <html> 
    <head> 
       <title>Bienvenido Usuario</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 

    <p> 
    <b>Buen dia estimado usuario 
    </b>. 
    </p> 
    </body> 
    </html> '; 
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n'; 
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n';

    while ($des = mysqli_fetch_array($rpt)) {
        $destinatario = $des['email'];
        mail($destinatario,$asunto,$cuerpo,$headers);
    }
```

Comment: de casualidad no es la misma que: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66222/env%c3%ado-de-alerta-por-correo-electr%c3%b3nico-el-problema-es-que-no-envia-los-correos ? De ser diferente, ¿Podrías decirme dónde se diferencian por favor?

Comment: como dice @Jorny, en una sola línea verás que te hace falta un espacio antes del where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que tal con esta:

> Todo en una linea

```
$sql = "SELECT agenda.*, usuario.email FROM agenda INNER JOIN usuario ON agenda.idusuario = usuario.idusuario WHERE fecha_fin = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Para esto sería correcto usar la siguiente consulta SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE prom_entrega >= curdate() + interval + 4 DAY;
```

De acuerdo a las necesidades sobre fechas se adecua cambiando
el intervalo a 7, 15, o 30 DAY, etc.

El resto del código está bien.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que va el segundo `+`? Porque así parecería que lo estás tratando como un entero, en vez de `interval 4 day`